# Как увеличить скорость вставки в коллекцию Set?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

У меня есть ученический вариант коллекции типа `Set` на основе массива, и мне дали задание увеличить скорость метода `add`. Но я что-то никак не пойму, как именно это сделать.

Как увеличить скорость вставки?

Код:

```
public class ArraySimpleSet<E> implements SetArray<E> {

    private E[] values;

    public ArraySimpleSet() {
        values = (E[]) new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            private int index = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index < values.length;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                return values[index++];
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(e);
        if (notExistDuplicate(e)) {
            try {
                E[] temp = values;
                values = (E[]) new Object[temp.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(temp, 0, values, 0, temp.length);
                values[values.length - 1] = e;
                sortByHashCode();
                return true;
            } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return values.length;
    }

    private boolean notExistDuplicate(E elem) {
        for (E e : values) {
            if (e.equals(elem))
                return false;

        }
        return true;
    }

    private void sortByHashCode() {
        int len = (values.length - 1);
        for(int i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (values[j].hashCode() < values[j + 1].hashCode()) {
                    E temp = values[j + 1];
                    values[j + 1] = values[j];
                    values[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сделать несколько улучшений:

1. `notExistDuplicate` реализовать в виде *бинарного поиска*, т.к. это возможно, потому что у вас массив отсортирован по hashcod'ам объектов
2. `sortByHashCode` реализовать при помощи *quick sort*, или *merge sort*, или любой другой алгоритм с лучшей асимптотикой, чем *O(n^2)*
3. Можно сделать вставку хитрее - не сортировать каждый раз новый массив. Т.е. `notExistDuplicate` возвращает индекс элемента - если элемент найден или *- (position + 1)* если объект не найден. Тогда нужно будет лишь скопировать элементы из массива, вставив при этом новый элемент в ячейку с индексом *position*.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. По поводу пункта 3, я не понял каким образом notExistDuplicate будет знать необходимую ячейку? Значит там придется все равно сортировку применить? Тогда какая разница там или здесь ее вызывать на производительность не влияет. Или я как-то не так вас понял?

Comment: @Павел метод будет производить бинарный поиск, в ходе которого будет выяснен исходный индекс элемента или же позиция на которой должен быть. Да, сортировка обязательна. Метод вызывается один раз, но за счет того что он будет возвращать индекс, а не значение boolean мы в дальнейшем можем уменьшить количество операций, за счет этого собственно и весь boost

Comment: >>>Да, сортировка обязательна. Метод вызывается один раз<<< а когда он вызывается в начале когда первый элемент добавляется нет смысла там нечего еще сортировать, а потом когда наступает этот один раз?

Comment: у вас есть отсортированный массив (пустой массив по умолчанию отсортирован). вызываем метод notExistDuplicate получаем индекс, если индекс со знаком плюс данный элемент уже есть в массиве. Иначе его нет, то мы создаем массив длины + 1 и производим копирование с учетом позиции на которую должен встать новый элемент. метод sortByHashCode в данном случае не нужен. но если не выполнять п.3 то можно обойтись п.1-п.2. по идеи первый вариант должен быть быстрее, но все зависит от размера массива, если он не большой, то разницы особой не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Не сортируйте массив при каждой вставке. Он уже отсортирован. Найдет место для нового элемента используя бинарный поиск. Расширяйте массив и вставляйте.